# When to use close vs Up navigation/Back icon in screens

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-bottomappbar

When should I use the `close` and when the `up navigation` icon in screens.

The only references I found were

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72038/back-vs-close-icon-in-material-design
https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#full-screen-dialog

Material Design says about FullScreen-Dialogs:

> Avoid any navigation icon other than “X.” The up arrow (1) indicates the view’s state is being saved, which isn’t the case in a full-screen dialog.

I guess the fact I'm using a BottomAppBar makes this question more complex.

For instance, Google's Task app is using a BottomAppBar too.

[image]

When clickig on an existing listview item a full screen fragment opens but with an `up navigation` icon

[image]

whereas the click on `New task list` from the navigation drawer opens a full screen fragment with a `close` icon.

[image]

By clicking on the FAB a bottom sheet opens for adding a task

[image]

Shouldn't the **edit task** (second) screen show a `close` icon and wouldn't it be also more consistent when on clicking the fab the same screen like the edit screen is showing?

Can someone be more clear about that, when its more appropriate to use `close` and when `up navigation` icon?

Answer (score 0):

If you read this article https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal you can see that it is encouraged that your app should not add  a Back button to the UI. This is because in most cases, the system already maintains a back stack of activities. So if you have have an option to go with close, then you should choose that over up navigation. This of course is not ALWAYS the case, but true most of the times.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you have a one activity multiple fragments architecture you have master/detail screens most of time. Here its appropriate to use the up icon so when would I use a close icon? I often see the close icon when state has to be saved but for instance a settings screen always have a up icon...